# Can we use class components as children for functional components in React?

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, components, children

Can we have stateful components as children for a stateless functional component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

```js
class B extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Class Component</div>
  }
}

const A = () => <div className="a">Stateless Functional Component <B /></div>

ReactDOM.render(<A />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.a {background: red; padding: 5px;}

.a div {background: green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure no problem, you just need to be aware that it re-renders the children if you didn't redefined shouldComponentUpdate or to use `React.memo`

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return (this.props.val !== nextProps.val);
}
```

For further reading:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate